# Vague [editor] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

The [editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editor) tag could be used for many purposes - is a question tagged with it requesting a text, video or image editor?

I think this tag should be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed, [editor](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/editor) is too ambiguous. It should be renamed to more precise tags such as [text-editors](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/text-editors), [video-editing](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-editing), etc.

Aaaand it's gone.

Comment: For consistency, shouldn't video-editing be renamed to video-editor?

Comment: @Bernhard I kind of prefer the tag to be about the activity than about the software itself. But “text editor” is an established phrase, “text editing” less so. For video, it's the opposite.

Comment: Didn't think about it that way, but it still seems inconsistent or arbitrary.

Comment: @Bernhard Natural language tends to be that way.